# reshaping the list to write select statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in this format:
[image]

and I want to select the rows that have specific class based on previous output of other operations, the problem is that the previous output is formatted like 
`most=["['books']"]`, so when I tried to write the select statement I wrote it like this:

```
df.loc[str([df['class'][0]])==most[0]]
```

However, I got this error:

```
~\Anaconda3\mianaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1789                 if not ax.contains(key):
-> 1790                     error()
   1791             except TypeError as e:

~\Anaconda3\mianaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in error()
   1784                                .format(key=key,
-> 1785                                        axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
   1786 

KeyError: 'the label [True] is not in the [index]'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-604a94f3536a> in <module>
----> 1 df.loc[str([df['class'][0]])==most[0]]

~\Anaconda3\mianaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1476 
   1477             maybe_callable = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1478             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1479 
   1480     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

~\Anaconda3\mianaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1909 
   1910         # fall thru to straight lookup
-> 1911         self._validate_key(key, axis)
   1912         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1913 

~\Anaconda3\mianaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1796                 raise
   1797             except:
-> 1798                 error()
   1799 
   1800     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

~\Anaconda3\mianaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in error()
   1783                 raise KeyError(u"the label [{key}] is not in the [{axis}]"
   1784                                .format(key=key,
-> 1785                                        axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
   1786 
   1787             try:

KeyError: 'the label [True] is not in the [index]'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: is most a list? your statement doesn't seem correct try - `df.loc[df['class'] == most[0]]`

Comment: yes a list I wrote in the post that most=["['books']"]

Comment: Please share **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve]. I know there is an answer which works, but using `eval()` is a bad idea and odds are there are design issues in your program. I think solving those poor design choices is far better than digging yourself into a deeper hole.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 df.loc[df['class'] == eval(most[0])[0]]
```

your string must be converted to an array, and then looked up to get the string in the array which is a string.